# Ruby: Strip significant digits from number?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Suppose I have the number `1.29999`. I want to just have `1.2` without the trailing `9`s. Note, I don't want it to round to `1.3`. How do I do this? I know there's the number helper, but I can't seem to get this working *outside* of a view. Any ideas?

For instance, `number_with_precision 111.2345, :precision => 2` does not work if I just put it in a normal model function.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another approach is to multiply by 100, truncate, then divide by 100.0:

```
$ irb --simple-prompt
>> (1.29999999*100).truncate/100.0
=> 1.29
```

Making it a method:

```
>> def truncate_to_two (x)
>>   (x * 100).truncate/100.0
>> end
=> nil
>> truncate_to_two 6342.899
=> 6342.89
>> truncate_to_two -322.11892
=> -322.11
>> truncate_to_two 244.9342
=> 244.93
```

Comment: This is better than my to_s approach.

Answer (score 1):

It's rudimentary, but you can do use string manipulation instead of math to do it. Example:

```
x = 1.29999
truncated = x.to_s.match(/(\d+\.\d{2})/)[0]  # assumes the format "n.nn" with 2 or more digits of precision; the regex can be expanded to handle more cases
```

Comment: +1 I like this because it is easy to extend to negative numbers by making the regex be `/(-?\d+\.\d{2})/)[0]`

Answer (score 0):

You can always `include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper` in your model to get access to the helpers.